# What is the performance of `count` on a Clojure set?

Tags: clojure

So, I read that the `count` operation is **O(1)** for a Clojure vectors, lists and maps.

```
(count [1 2 3]) ;=> 3
```

But is it also **O(1)** for a Clojure set? I imagine it *probably* is, but I'm not really sure how to find out. I had a quick read of http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Sets, but couldn't see the info there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is `O(1)`

You can verify this by observing that `clojure.lang.PersistentSet` maintains a `_count` field in the Java source code:

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentList.java

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right place to look! I can see now the `Counted` interface that indicates O(1) performance for `count`, and that PersistentSet implements it. `(instance? clojure.lang.Counted #{:a :b: :c}) => true`

Comment: Yes `Counted` is a useful marker interface to check for. Though note that it doesn't strictly *guarantee* O(1) behaviour - you have to check the actual concrete class implementation to be sure of that. In theory, someone could implement `Counted` badly with O(n^2) performance or worse....