# Largest collections first

Tags: clojure

I have a list of lists. And I want the biggest lists to come at the beginning. This works, but can take a long time:

```
(reverse (sort-by count coll))
```

What is a more efficient way of doing this, presumably in one go?

Comment: `(sort-by (comp - count) coll)` I'm sure the slowness comes from the counting, not the reversing.

Comment: I'm led to believe there's a count field in every kind of collection, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079774/what-is-the-performance-of-count-on-a-clojure-set). If there actually is then counting should be quick.

Comment: Not every kind. Are you actually working with a list of PersistentLists? If they are lazy seqs, they are not Counted.

Comment: They are lazy, so they need to be forced into being PersistentLists by using `into`. That's my understanding. The `into` step will make them not lazy and hence the count field will be there. But of course the `into` step will now take some time.

Answer (score 1):

thank you galdre for pointing out my error

don't use lazy sequences

a quick demo:

```
user> (let [xs (doall(repeat 1000000 1))]
        (time (count xs)))
"Elapsed time: 29.393886 msecs"
1000000
user> (let [xs (into [] (repeat 1000000 1))]
        (time (count xs)))
"Elapsed time: 0.013346 msecs"
1000000
```

Comment: (let [xs (into () (repeat 1000000 1))] (time (count xs)))

Comment: A LazySeq, evaluated or not, is not Counted. A PersistentList is Counted. So there's no benefit to be gained by using PersistentVector over using PersistentList. Secondly, if the problem is that the lazyseq is slow to be counted, I'm not sure that dumping it into a vector so that you can read the count field is any faster.

Comment: @galdre I was mistaken. I fixed my example